# UIActivityViewController time lag in appearance of sharing options

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

There is a time lag between tapping of an option (present in UIActivityViewController eg: **Notes app** , **Mail app**) and the appearance of the respective controllers (Notes sharing controller, MFMessageController).

I want to show a loader in this time frame, but there seems to be no delegate methods of UIActivityController for doing so.

Can anyone suggest the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up subclassing the `UIActivityViewController` with the only addition being sending a notification after `viewDidLoad` completed.

Thus, I spin an activity indicator which I stop when I receive said notification.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wanted to use the solution of `DrMickeyLauer` without using notifications, you could instead pass your custom ActivityController a closure:

```swift
class CustomActivityController: UIActivityViewController {
    
    private let onViewDidLoad: (() -> Void)
    
    // We create a new initializer that adds an argument 
    init(activityItems: [Any], applicationActivities: [UIActivity]?, onViewDidLoad: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        self.onViewDidLoad = onViewDidLoad

        super.init(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // We execute the closure
        onViewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

To use it:

```swift
// Start animating your loading indicator

let activityVC = CustomActivityController(
    activityItems: [...],
    applicationActivities: [...],
    onViewDidLoad: {
        // Stop animating your loading indicator
    }
)
```